# Creating a dataframe in R using two datasets

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two datasets, and I need to create a dataframe that allows me to select one column for each data set, and create a boxplot. For instance, one dataset has information about Treatment, and the other dataset has a Shannon diversity index measurement

````
library(ggplot2)
library(vegan)
library(tidyverse)

# This code will create a matrix with 30 columns representing species and 10 rows representing communities.
# The object will be called "community_matrix"

set.seed(2)
community1=matrix(
  sample(0:250,300,replace=T),nrow=10,
  dimnames=list(paste("community",1:10,sep=""),paste("sp",1:30,sep="")))
community2=matrix(
  sample(50:200,300,replace=T),nrow=10,
  dimnames=list(paste("community",11:20,sep=""),paste("sp",1:30,sep="")))
community_matrix<- rbind(community1,community2)

#This code will create a metadata table depicting the treatments.

m1<- as.data.frame(list(paste("community",1:10,sep=""), paste("T1")))
colnames(m1)<- c("Communities", "Treatment")
m2<- as.data.frame(list(paste("community",11:20,sep=""), paste("T2")))
colnames(m2)<- c("Communities", "Treatment")
metadata<-rbind(m1,m2)

# 1- Calculate the Shannon diversity index for all samples using the vegan package

raremax<-min(rowSums(community_matrix))
rarefied_data<- rrarefy(community_matrix, raremax)
H <- vegan::diversity(rarefied_data, index = "shannon")

# Using the Shannon diversity measurements obtained in step1, make a graph with a boxplot for each treatment - customize the plot as you wish```
````

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to join/merge the data. The only trick here is that H is a named vector rather than a data frame. But if we use a bit of `dplyr` to fo the merge, we can also use `tibble` to turn it into a data frame. This should work

```
tibble::enframe(H, name="Communities", value="H") |> 
  left_join(metadata) |> 
  ggplot() + 
    aes(Treatment, H) + 
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image: boxplot]

Comment: community_shannon <- cbind(H, metadata$Treatment)
print(community_shannon) I was trying to use the cbind function, to join the two columns and then proceed to do the boxplot, but I dont know it that would be okay??

Comment: If you know for sure that the two tables have the exact same values in the exact same order, then `cbind` would be fine. In general a merge/join is "safer" because it actually checks that the values match but in this case it's not really an issue.

Comment: OH, okay thank you so much!! Can I use the same enframe() to calculate the t-test?

Comment: The `enframe` just gets around the `cbind` step. If you use `cbind` you don't really need `enframe`. But you should be able to use the resulting data frame from either method with the `t.test` function.